# How do I get TempData value in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to catch Tempdata[] / Viewbag value in jQuery.

I have added an `InvDate` value to `TempData` in my controller, and I'm trying to read it in a view.

But this does not work:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Back").click(function () {
        alert("ok");
        var InvDate = @TempData["InvDate"];
        alert(InvDate)
    });
});
</script>
```

I need help - I'm working in ASP.NET MVC using VS 2017 Express

Answer (score 3):

Here it is:

[Demo_link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zU7D30)

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
     public ActionResult Index()
     {
        TempData["test"]="MyName";
        return View();
     }
    }
```

View Code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var data = '@TempData["test"]';
    alert(data);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#Back").click(function () {
        alert("ok");
            var InvDate = '@TempData["InvDate"]';
        alert(InvDate)

    });

});
</script>
```

use this.
I just added string in @TempData["InvDate"].